# Custom Metrics sent through DogStatsD is not listed in DataDog

Tags: java, docker, metrics, datadog

We are currently using dd-agent to trace our application hosted in Docker container. Here both agent and application are hosted in container. Now, we are planning to push some custom metrics to datadog using DogStatsD from our application(Spring-boot).

We followed the steps for submitting the metrics from "Metric Submission: DogStatsD" documentation. But we are not seeing any metrics in metrics summary/metrics explorer. We using docker-compose to build and run our application.

Could someone help me to resolve this?